# Explode Pandas dataframe with mismatched number of elements

Tags: python, pandas, list, explode

I work on a dataset like this one and I want to explode it with the content of each list.

```
index    col1      col2      col3
    1   [A,B]     [,xx]     [1,2]
    2   [A,C]   [zz,xx]     [3,4]
    3    [D,]   [zz,yy]     [2,2]
```

However, the missing values in `[,xx]` and in `[D,]` generate errors and I am looking for a way to fill the empty position in these lists.

My idea is to fill the blank in the lists to get something like `[NaN,xx]` and `[D,NaN]`, without specifying the index in the list because the blank is not always at the same position.

How can I achieve this please ?

Comment: can you provide code of input? when list or dictionary is included in a cell like this question, it is clearer to provide the input as code.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example, including the errors you are encountering

Comment: `[,xx]` wouldn't be valid python, please provide a DataFrame constructor of your example. You could provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` as [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`[,xx]` (or `[,'xx']`) could not be a valid python object.

```
[,'xx']
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Only `['xx']` would be, but in this case there is no way to differentiate something that would be converted to `['xx', NaN]` or `[NaN, 'xx']`.

Thus, assuming that you have **strings representations of list-like objects** (`'[,xx]'`), you could strip the `[`/`]` and split on `,` before exploding:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

out = (df[cols]
       .applymap(lambda x: x.strip('[]').split(','))  # convert to lists
       .explode(cols)                                 # explode
       .join(df.drop(columns=cols))[df.columns]       # add other columns
      )
```

*NB. in most recent versions of pandas, replace `applymap` by `map`.*

Output:

```
   index col1 col2 col3
0      1    A         1
0      1    B   xx    2
1      2    A   zz    3
1      2    C   xx    4
2      3    D   zz    2
2      3        yy    2
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2, 3],
                   'col1': ['[A,B]', '[A,C]', '[D,]'],
                   'col2': ['[,xx]', '[zz,xx]', '[zz,yy]'],
                   'col3': ['[1,2]', '[3,4]', '[2,2]']})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data as below and if you want to replace your null values with some special character you can do below.

`np.nan` is nothing but the null in python.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    [['A','B'], ['A','C'], ['D',np.nan]],
    [[np.nan,'xx'], ['zz','xx'], ['zz','yy']],
    [[1,2], [3,4],[2,2]]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
special_char = 'NaN'

def replace_null(x):
  if isinstance(x, list):
    return [replace_null(item) for item in x]
  else:
    return x if not pd.isna(x) else special_char

df = df.applymap(replace_null)
print(df)
```